# egs template showing only plain text in email sent from nodemailer nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs, nodemailer

email showing only plain text, css applied not render in email

```
import express from 'express'
import Email from "../Model/email.js"
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"
import ejs from "ejs"
```

```
await ejs.renderFile("views/mail.ejs", { name: 'Stranger' }, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        var mainOptions = {from: 'exapmple@gmail.com',to: 'a@gmail.com',
                            subject: 'Hello',html: data }
```

tranporter

```
      transporter.sendMail(mainOptions, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {console.log(err)
             } else {console.log('Message sent')}
        })
    }
   })
```

Comment: Can You show your template (mail.ejs) ?

Comment: <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>OAuth Tutorials</title>
        <style>
          
            nav{
                background: #ff5353;
                padding: 20px 10px;
            }
            nav ul{
                max-width: 960px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
            }
            display: block;
            }           
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
        </nav>      
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Can You add your code into your question post ? :-/

Comment: Where are the static files ? Can you show folder structure of your project ? Add all code carefully..;-)

Comment: if inline css is applied its working, if i apply css in header  section its not working